# CalendarProvider stops inserting recurrence instances after querying instance table with long period

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I create a recurrence event in google calendar called "Rec1".

Then in a sample app I query the instance table:

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 1, 1);
GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(2050, 1, 1);
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(builder,c.getTimeInMillis());
ContentUris.appendId(builder,c2.getTimeInMillis());
Cursor cursor2=getContentResolver().query(builder.build(),null,null,null,null);
```

Then I return to google calendar and create a new recurrence event called "Rec2". The event is created successfully but nothing is shown!. I query the `Events` table and see that "Rec2" is created but if I query the `Instances` table the last row is "Rec1".

I cannot insert recurrence event anymore even if I uninstall the sample app. No matter what calendar app I use (Google calendar, Sunrise, create event dynamically in code,..) and no matter what calendar I use (google, exchange, locally created calendar,...).

It seems that `CalendarProvider` doesn't generate instances for recurrence events anymore. (Inserting non-recurrence events is still fine, just recurrence is the problem).

**The only solution** that I find to return to normal life about recurrences is removing another recurrence event. So If I delete "Rec1", "Rec2" is inserted in `Instance` table and is shown in calendar apps!

**Note:** If I repeat the whole scenario but with this time period:

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 4, 1);
GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 5, 1);
```

No problem is happened and "Rec2" is inserted and shown without needing to delete "Rec1".

**Note:** I tried this scenario many times and the problem happens in emulators, Nexus 5, Nexus 5x, Sony z1 compact, but not in Samsung Note 4!

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any stack traces in the log? AFAIK Android's CalendarProvider still uses the deprecated Time class which suffers from the year 2038 problem. Does that also happen when you don't use years beyond 2038?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you query all instances in a range of 50 years? The result can easily contain several thousands of instances.

Comment: @Marten I had tried this with smaller periods and it worked fine. But you are right. I tried a long period that is beyond 2038 and everything worked fine. Then I tried a small period that that overlaps 2038 (2037-2039) and the problem occurred.

Comment: @Marten You are right. Actually this is not what I really want. But I am confused why I can destroy such an important part of system with a line of code!

Comment: I think the calendar provider only uses the Time class for recurrence expansion. The only option you have is to avoid dates after the year 2037. Samsung may have fixed it but I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: This is because Google Docs state that "For recurring events, multiple rows are automatically generated that correspond to multiple occurrences of that event."
Hence one instance of recurring event is necessary.

Comment: @Misagh I have also same problem, Can you tell me the solution if you've already found?